# Monit log monitoring (long log lines!)

Tags: monit

Monit is monitoring a log file with very long lines and when a content match is occuring, only part of the log line is displayed (both on the email alert and on /var/log/monit.log). I looked into the documentation and couldn't find anything helpful, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The ultimate documentation is the code itself.  Have you looked at the matching code?

Comment: @Frobbit, just found it: validate.c:111 #define MATCH_LINE_LENGTH 512
Guess it is not configurable.. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you have found an issue that you should fix for yourself.
1. Clone https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/ on bitbucket
2. Find the option handling code
3. Add the parameter in the same style as other, whether you agree with the pattern or not
4. Change the locations that use the define to use the new parameter 
5. Submit a pull request with your change